# Nextjs - router.prefetch doesn't prefetch

Tags: javascript, next.js, prefetch, guess.js

I have followed the instructions here in https://guess-js.github.io/docs/next.

First run the command:

```
mkdir guess-next && cd guess-next && touch package.json
```

Then fill the `/package.json` with:

```
{
  "name": "guess-next",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "export": "npm run build && next export -o guess"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^6.1.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "guess-webpack": "^0.1.6"
  }
}
```

Then run the command:

```
npm i
```

Then run the command:

```
mkdir components && cd components && touch layout.js
```

Then fill the `/components/layouts.js` with:

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';
import { guess } from 'guess-webpack/api';

import Link from 'next/link';
import Head from 'next/head';

const layout = ({ router, children, title = ' Next.js + Guess.js' }) => {

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined')
    Object.keys(guess()).forEach(p => router.prefetch(p));

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>{title}</title>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <header>
        <nav>
          <Link href="/">
            <a>Home</a>
          </Link>{' '}
          <Link href="/example">
            <a>Example</a>
          </Link>{' '}
          <Link href="/about">
            <a>About</a>
          </Link>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <div className="content">{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(layout);
```

Then create directory named: `pages` in the root.

Then create the files inside the directory created.

```
pages/
├── about.js
├── example.js
├── index.js
└── media.js
```

Then fill the content of each file like below (Only change the [PAGE_NAME] depending on the page):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/layout';

export default () => (
  <Layout>
    [PAGE_NAME]
  </Layout>
);
```

Then for `media.js` put the content of:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default () => (
  <Layout>
    About
    <br />
    You can find the{' '}
    <Link href="/media">
      <a>media page here</a>
    </Link>
  </Layout>
);
```

Then inside `next.config.js` file put:

```
const { GuessPlugin } = require('guess-webpack');

module.exports = {
  webpack: function(config, { isServer }) {
    if (isServer) return config;
    config.plugins.push(
      new GuessPlugin({
        reportProvider() {
          return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('./routes.json')));
        }
      })
    );
    return config;
  }
};
```

Then inside `routes.json` put:

```
{
  "/": {
    "/example": 80,
    "/about": 20
  },
  "/example": {
    "/": 20,
    "/media": 0,
    "/about": 80
  },
  "/about": {
    "/": 20,
    "/media": 80
  },
  "/media": {
    "/": 33,
    "/about": 33,
    "/example": 34
  }
}
```

And finally run the commands:

```
npm run build && npm run start
```

Now when I open the browser to open the `localhost:3000`, the next.js is working and I can navigate to different pages, but the problem is that it doesn't prefetch the other pages.

My cache is disabled.

In the `/components/layouts.js` file, I even added this line below to check if it works statically:

```
router.prefetch('/index.js')
router.prefetch('/example.js')
router.prefetch('/about.js')
router.prefetch('/media.js')
```

No luck.

**UPDATE**

I got that it is receiving the data in protocol `http1.1`, can this be the problem? How to convert it to `http2`.